# Spring Security Check if User is logged in

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my controller, I am trying to check if a logged in user made the request, or if a non-logged in user made the request.  The controller requires no permissions, but for logging purposes I'd like to record the username if the request was made by a logged in user, and "guest" if the request was made by a non-logged in user.  When I do not use the @Secured tag, `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` always returns null, regardless of whether the user is logged in.  Additionally, I have tried passing in `Principal principal` as a method parameter, but this does not work either, and the controller method is never called in the case of a non-logged in user.  How can I get the username if the user is logged in, without using the @Secured tag?

Comment: There should be returning the authentication object for logged in user. Seems like there is an issue with your configuration. Can you post your configuration.

Comment: There is no issue with the configuration, all the other secured methods work fine.

Comment: You won't get any help with the prescribed description... It is too overstated to tell that you configuration is fine, then it will be up to you then to solve the issue by yourself!

Comment: Principal is not able to be passed as a parameter, as there is no principal for logged in users.  I cannot use @Secured since non-logged in users should be able to use this method.  I think the lack of @Secured makes it so `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` always returns null.  This is why I am asking if there is another way that I do not know of.  There is nothing wrong with the configuration, as every other method, controller, etc I use is completely fine, this is just a special case, and I'm not sure if Spring can handle it.